# Trying to parse a text file for a string and print a value

Tags: perl, parsing, text

I'm trying to parse 40+ text files that are in a directory for the word "Phone:" and print the phone number that comes after the string.  I'm a super perl novice so any help is greatly appreciated.
I had to comment out the strict or it wouldn't run,

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use strict;
use warnings;

my $DIR = "/Ask";
opendir $DIR, '.' or die "opendir .: $!\n";
my @files = grep /\.txt$/i, readdir $DIR;
closedir $DIR;

print "Got ", scalar @files, " files\n";

my %seen = ();
foreach my $file (@files) {
    open my $FILE, '<', $file or die "$file: $!\n";
    while (<$FILE>) {
        #print "test\n";
        if (/^phone\s*(.*)\r?$/i) {
            $seen{$1} = 1;
            foreach my $addr ( sort keys %seen ) {
                print "$addr\n";
            }
        }
    }
    close $FILE;
}
```

it sees the files but never seems to match the argument and print the results.
I can also convert the files to html easily and parse them that way.

Thanks for all of the assistance so far.  Here are a few more questions that have come up and an example of the files that I'm parsing:

Here's an example of the short files I'm parsing-                    Agilent Technologies,Inc. Headquarters. Toll-Free: +1 877-424-4536, phone: 4083458886.Fax: +1 408-345-8474 Address: 5301 Stevens Creek Blvd - I think the problem I'm having is that the phone: isn't always at the start of the line.  If I modify my files and put it there all works well but I think the script has problems finding it in the middle of a row.  Ideas?

Comment: You may want to add a Perl tag to the question to get more pertinent viewers.

Comment: Do you need a `:` after `/^phone` in your regex?

Comment: yep, change your regex to `^phone\s*:\s*(.*)\r?$`

Comment: You should also un-comment `use strict;`

Comment: Disabling `strict` is equally good idea as putting tape over car indicator lights. In both cases it looks like it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Few things

- Never comment out `use strict;`
- Don't include a newline after your `die` messages, that tells die to hide the line number and file messages
- Your using %seen to make your phone numbers unique.  Therefore output the results of them outside the file processing loop.  Additionally, define %seen as lexical to the outside loop or phone numbers from previous files will still be around.
- If you aren't getting any results, then your regex is probably not matching.  Perhaps the anchor is too limitting: `^`

Here's some cleanup of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $DIR = "/Ask";

my @files = do {
    opendir my $dh, '.' or die "opendir .: $!";
    grep /\.txt$/i, readdir $dh;
};

print "Got ", scalar @files, " files\n";

foreach my $file (@files) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$file: $!";

    my %seen;

    while (<$fh>) {
        if (/^phone\s*(.*)$/i) {
            $seen{$1} = 1;
        }
    }

    foreach my $addr ( sort keys %seen ) {
        print "$addr\n";
    }

    close $fh;
}
```

Comment: thanks to all so far.  how about parsing html or rtf? first script worked well, second one gave me the following error: Bad symbol for dirhandle at parse2.pl line 10 - thanks, Tony

Comment: I had a typo at line 10.  Corrected.

Comment: thanks.  what about returning multiple strings like phone,address,zip?

Comment: Anything is possible.  However, you've shared no information about the nature of your data, so it is literally impossible to advise you in more detail.  If you want to parse additional fields, you'll just need to program that parsing.

Comment: Here's an example of the short files I'm parsing-                    Agilent Technologies,Inc. Headquarters.
Toll-Free: +1 877-424-4536, phone: 4083458886.Fax: +1 408-345-8474
Address: 5301 Stevens Creek Blvd - I think the problem I'm having is that the phone: isn't always at the start of the line.  If I modify my files and put it there all works well but I think the script has problems finding it in the middle of a row.  Ideas?

Comment: It's cool to include a comment to inform of additional information.  However, you should include the literal additional information as an edit to the end of your question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to chomp() each line to remove the newline character "\n" that accompanies each line:

```
while (<$FILE>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^phone\s*(.*)\r?$/i) {
        $seen{$1} = 1;
        foreach my $addr ( sort keys %seen ) {
            print "$addr\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can make your regular expression multi-line by adding the 's' modifier, which will allow your ".*" to consume newline characters:

```
while (<$FILE>) {
    if (/^phone\s*(.*)\r?$/is) {
        $seen{$1} = 1;
        foreach my $addr ( sort keys %seen ) {
            print "$addr\n";
        }
    }
}
```